# 100-Pin QPF on top and bottom of PCB?

Tags: pcb, manufacturing

Can one place large packages (QFP-100) on top and bottom side of (same) PCB?

Of course I could hand-solder them but since I also have some small QFN packages I suspect will need to use reflow soldering, in which case I'm afraid the larger packages will fall off the board or at least will have trouble aligning property.

Comment: The thickness of your pcb matters. Thinner and it will transfer more heat faster, causing issues. And do your qfns have large center ground pads?

Comment: The QFN have a center thermal pad but are rather small 3x3mm. The thickness will be standard 1.6mm

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this can be done.  However, boards with components on both sides will cost more to build up because it requires extra steps.  As you say, you don't want the chips on the bottom to fall off while the ones on top are being soldered.

This is usually dealt with one of two ways.  When the part has low weight to solder pad area, then it will stay in place just from the surface tension of the molten solder.  For heavier parts, usually a kind of glue is used.

Double-sided boards are common enough, but when doing something like this it is still a good idea to talk to your assembly house first to get some idea what their processes are and what you can do on your end to make things simpler for them, and therefore cheaper for you.

Comment: Since this is a research project with little funding we will probably manufacture in-house (hobbyist-like reflow oven, I'm afraid). Nevertheless, when glueing the heavier parts, how can I assure they 'align' to their pads?

Comment: @Arne First solder, then glue?

Comment: First glue then solder I suspect. Or do you suggest reflowing two times - top and bottom side one after another?

Comment: got confused about your nicknames... anyway I think you should go with a double reflow.

Comment: +1 reflow twice is really the only option frankly

Comment: @VladimirCravero When reflowing the second time, what kind of glue should I use? Do I really need to glue the bigger parts?

Comment: @Arne I don't have a clue. I suppose any thermal resistant glue can do but I don't know if there's something specific...

Comment: @Arne: I think you have two options: 1 - Design the board for all SMD parts on one side.  2 - Get the board professionally built.  Trying to do this yourself, especially since you don't seem to know how, is going to be very expensive in the long run.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You are probably right. The questionable part is the only (larger) one that might end up on the back, so I suppose I will solder it by hand.

Comment: @Arne: Unless you have a hot air soldering station, you're not going to solder a 3x3 mm QFN by hand.  Even then it is tricky, but at least possible.

Comment: The one eligible for hand soldering is the QFP-100. The 3x3 QFN is the reason to start the whole reflow thing in the first place.